# QGIS: Geometry By Expression - collect geometries from self selecting line excluding $currentfeature and change geometry

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, geometry-generator

[image: Problem to fix]

I am looking for a solution in QGIS in form of an expression that is collecting the geometries that intersect the $currentfeature ( excluding this one - the orange line ) and than iterate over the collection of geometries and move for each geometry the end_point to the start_point of the excluded geometry like in the picture above.

What I have tried so far:

**Option 1 (aggregate-function):**

I am able to collect the geometries but I have a hard time to find a way to access/iterate the given result beeing <geometry: MultiLineString> in such way that i can call the function make_line from end_point(geometry(blue_1) and end_point(geometry(blue_2) to the end_point(geometry(orange))

/* IF for excluding the orange line, but if "number" is containing an value I will have a problem.Any idea of a better solution that excludes the $currentfeature? */

```
if("number" IS NULL,
collect_geometries(
aggregate(layer:=@layer, 
aggregate:='array_agg',
expression:=$geometry,  
filter:= intersects( @geometry, geometry(@parent) ) ) )
```

**Option 2 (overlay-function):**

The good thing about the second option is that i get the feature as an array in comparison with the first option. I know that with geometry(feature) i can get the geometry of one feature.

*Side Question*: How do I access the geometries of the array of features ?

```
if("number" IS NULL,
overlay_intersects(@layer,$currentfeature,limit:=-1),'')
```

the result hier beeing: [ <feature: 3>, <feature: 2> ]

=============================================================================

I would like a solution for each option because I am truly willing to learn more about the mechanism behind and how to use  them properly, especially how to iterate over the collection with array_foreach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1

In the case of Option 1, to exclude the current feature, you can add an extra clause in your filter: `@id <> feature_id(@parent)`.

The `aggregate` function returns an array so all you need to do is to use the `@element`s of that array in a `make_line` step, using `array_foreach`.

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        aggregate(
            layer:=@layer,
            aggregate:='array_agg',
            expression:=$geometry,
            filter:=intersects(@geometry, geometry(@parent)) AND (@id <> feature_id(@parent))
        ),
        make_line(start_point(@element),start_point(@geometry))
    )   
)
```

Note that the `@layer` variable may be a problem - you might need to replace with your actual layer ID.

Also note that despite excluding the current feature, this will still run for every feature, so you will end up with 3 multilinestrings - one for each original feature.

Obviously you can use your original `if("number" IS NULL,` clause to get around this.

### Option 2

I would use `overlay_intersects` rather than `overlay_nearest` as `overlay_nearest` will get non-intersecting lines as well as intersecting ones.

You can then use a similar approach to above using `array_foreach` and `make_line`.

```
array_foreach(
    overlay_intersects(@layer,@feature,limit:=-1),
    make_line(start_point(geometry(@element)),start_point(@geometry))
)
```

As above, the `@layer` variable may be a problem - you might need to replace with your actual layer ID.

Also note that $currentfeature is deprecated - use @feature (unless you are using an old version of QGIS).

Comment: I tried the solution and it works great. It would be much nicer if the output of the expression would be a SingleLineString rather then a MultiLineString where the blue line just shifts the end_point to the start_point of the orange one, and the orange line doesn't do nothing. I tried the two options with a if clause but the thing is that  if I write 'if("number" IS NULL, ...expression...,NULL)'  the output would be 1x <geometry: MultiLineString> and 2x NULL ( geometries). I need then to delete the null geometries,split the multiline and get the values back for the blue line. Any ideea?

Comment: Probably ask it as a new question - I'm not clear on how you are determining the orange feature (is it always where "number" IS NULL?). I imagine it would be fairly easy to adapt Option 2 to create 2 LineStrings but depends on the details.

Comment: Yes you are right the orange line has allways the same value NULL and is allways in the opposite direction to the blue ones touching it. To have a littel bit of context : the blue lines have at the start_point a house wich passes a value ( in the example for testing purposes is it the "number" - Field). So the blue lines have allways a value and the orange one not. What I am trying to do is find the blue ones intersecting the orange one and shift the end_point of the blue ones to the start of the orange one, and then getting rid of the orange line. Thank you for your help :)